# MinGW with Code::Blocks warnings look like errors

Tags: warnings, mingw, codeblocks

Im developing an app with MinGW and Code::Blocks and i recently updated the MinGW to the last version, but now, when i compile my project, the warnings look like errors (red coloured) and when the compilation finish, all the warnings are counted as errors, so the final output looks like === Build finished: 50 errors, 0 warnings === but they are actually warnings, and the compilation is successful, I get the .exe file and it works fine.

But i would like to solve this problem, because when my app has real errors, they are mixed with the warnings, all in red, and its hard to find them.

Do you know what may cause this problem, and how to solve it?

Comment: Why not solve the warnings as well?

Comment: Update Code::Blocks too. Sounds like it may be parsing the result of MinGW wrong. And, BTW, it sounds like you're deliberately avoiding fixing warnings, which is BAD.

Comment: I can´t solve the warnings, because they are throwed by an extern library, Ogre3D. At least i dont know how to solve them :P

Comment: Alright; not much you can do about that then.

Comment: You're _sure_ that compilation is succeeding? You don't have `-Werrors` being passed to MinGW, or that the warnings really are errors now in newer MinGW?

Comment: Also [this](http://developer.berlios.de/bugs/?func=detailbug&bug_id=11611&group_id=5358) _may_ be pertinent if your new compiler is running in a non-English locale

Comment: Im sure that the compilation is successful, if i delete the .exe, and hit compile, i get a new working .exe. Also, the code is the same, so it should work.

Comment: Hmm, that could be the problem. Im gonna change it to english. EDIT: How can i change it to english? :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Lightness Races in Orbit found, The problem is that the Code::blocks parser doesnt work fine with non-english languajes. The solution is to make your compiler give output in english.